# Is Reinforced Polyethylene Construction Film safe for raised bed liners?

Tags: raised-beds

I am planning to build raised beds. For the longevity of the wood I would like to use plastic liners. Is [Reinforced Polyethylene Construction Film](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Americover-12-ft-x-100-ft-6-mil-String-Reinforced-Polyethylene-Construction-Film-PSR612/203635222) food safe?

If not, could anyone please suggest a food safe type of plastic liner?

Comment: I think you will run into drainage problems with non porous liners. How long do these beds need to last?

Comment: 3-4 year, I will have drainage holes in the bottom of the bed and feed out the liner